# MySql Php Applet Not connecting

Tags: mysql, html, japplet

im making this applet in netbeans.. i did run the application and it works!! i have some queries there and everything is fine. When i put it in my index.html, the queries wont work for some reason. Is the same database that im using in my page. Im working with Wamp 2.2, Netbeans 7.0.1.

```
<applet code="appletdesarrollo.appletprofesor" archive="AppletDesarrollo.jar"/>
```

This is how i am adding the jar to the page. And when i open the file in the gchrome, i can see the applet but theres some comboboxes that doesnt get filled!

Comment: Don't see how its connected to php. I assume your jar makes direct connection to mysql? And mysql allows it?

Comment: Yep, the jar make directs connections to the mysql, and the same jar running from netbeans, gets connected with the mysql. But in the htlm file, it doesnt connect. I tried the keytool thing i did read here, but still not connect. It says CLassnotFOUND: com.mysql.dbc.Driver

Comment: @dbncourt: Please don't retype error messages. Instead copy & paste them. That way we can be sure whether the `NoClassDefFoundError` refers to `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` or (as you typed it) `com.mysql.dbc.Driver`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is only a `ClassNotFound: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` error, then you are missing the JDBC connector jar file (mysql-connector-*.jar). This file should be in your `WEB-INF/lib` folder of your application. Or you can place it in your `JRE_HOME/lib/ext` folder so that it will be common for all the applications. An example of JRE_HOME/lib/ext is (in Windows) : C:\Program Files\java\jre6\lib\ext

Comment: Im pasting that jar too in the same folder where my page is located. In wamp i dont have WEB-INF/lib, or u mean some place else? Srry for this kind of questions, but this is my first application using applet with queries in a html file.

Comment: My mistake, I should not tell you about `WEB-INF/lib` just forget it (It is useful when you are deploying your html pages in TOMCAT server). And yes, the `mysql-connector-*.jar` wont be picked up from the same folder by your applet. The best place for you to put the `mysql-connector-*.jar` inside `JRE_HOME/lib/ext`. It must be a path like : `C:\Program Files\java\jre6\lib\ext`. There just paste the mysql-connector-*.jar

Comment: If you are interested in developing web-applications in Java, must read about what a APPLICATION SERVER is. You are in WAMP. That means APACHE is the server you are using for hosting html-page. But it is NOT a JAVA APPLICATION SERVER. It will just display your html page. And wont help anything about your java CLASSPATH. If you prefer using a proper Java Application Server (e.g. TOMCAT) then you will be familier with the DIRECTORY STRUCTURE of a JAVA WEB APPLICATION. Where do I need to paste the jar, where do I need to paste the class file, all will be mentioned in the Developers Guide.

Comment: Oh!! thx! had no idea! always thought JApplet could be embed in a htlm file and just work! Ill give it a try :D

Answer (score 0):

> ClassNotFound: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

The JDBC driver needs to be added to the run-time class-path of the applet.  Make a reference to it in the `archive` attribute of the `applet` element.

### Other matters

1. Does the applet reside at an URL where we can see it? What is the URL?
2. What is the (entire) HTML (of the smallest example you can make) that fails? But please [validate it](http://validator.w3.org/) first.  There are a number of errors even in that single line of HTML & GI/GO.
3. For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (of applet code).
4. Note that you should get this working in a desktop app. first, applets are very much harder to develop & deploy.
5. Once you have the working desktop app., launch it from a link using [Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).